# Update SQLite3 in PHP

Tags: centos, php, sqlite

I just checked my server's PHP  7.3.8 SQLite and its way old, 3.7.17, compared to the latest SQLite 3.29.0.

Is there a stable way to include the new sqlite into PHP? PHP.INI doesn't have any information as to if sqlite3.so is included as an extension, maybe it's build in?

If so, must I recompile the entire PHP?

Comment: How did you check the sqlite version?

Comment: By using `phpinfo()`